# Way to reference objects in Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to draw shapes based off of where on the screen existing shapes are, so that I only have to change the coordinates of one shape for all the others to shift appropriately. Is there some way to reference a rectangle's x coordinate when constructing another?

For example, the following code does not work as I thought it would:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 1000,600);

    var rectangleOne = paper.rect(100, 100, 100, 50);

    var rectangleTwo = paper.rect(rectangleOne.x, rectangleOne.y + 40, rectangleOne.width + 50, rectangleOne.height);
```

I get some error that "rectangleOne.x" is undefined and defaults to zero...Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks all!

Comment: can you try to grab the `x` attribute using the raphaeljs `attr` function? i.e. `rectangleOne.attr('x')` and `rectangleOne.attr('y')`. See http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr

Comment: Ah you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rectangleTwo = paper.rect(rectangleOne.attr('x'), rectangleOne.attr('y') + 40, rectangleOne.attr('width') + 50, rectangleOne.attr('height'));
```